# rtorrent with Seeds and Downloads

Tags: bittorrent, nice

I'm using rtorrent for a very long time. I'm fan. This is one of the greatest console torrent manager ever.

However, I can't found cool way to keep seeding.

My downloads separated into two directories, `Downloads` and `Seeds`. From time to time I'm keeping two instances of rtorrent simultaneously, one for `Downloads` another for `Seeds`.

Any torrent client eats disk operations very badly. I have couple of tricks to prevent disk stucks:

```
nice -n 20 chrt -i 0 ionice -c3 /usr/bin/rtorrent -o upload_rate=25000,download_rate=50000,max_uploads_global=100,max_peers=50,max_memory_usage=805306368
```

In this way `prio` of rtorrent is lowest one for the system. Anyway two instances competing and take my disk from time to time very evilly. My bash shell would hung for listing big directories, open files for editing, etc...

I'm trying to find the way to keep only one instance of rtorrent and save separations by directories `Downloads` and `Seeds`.

How can I launch rtorrent in such manner, that it wouldn't shuffle my Downloads and my Seeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found answer:

```
schedule = tied_directory,10,10,start_tied=
schedule = untied_directory,10,10,close_untied=
schedule = watch_directory_1,10,10,"load_start=/Downloads/torrents/*.torrent,d.set_directory=/Downloads/"
schedule = watch_directory_2,10,10,"load_start=/Downloads/Seed/torrents/*.torrent,d.set_directory=/Downloads/Seed/"
```